# jquery UI datetimepicker setup a common configuration

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have several different configuations for datetimepicker in my application some need a date picker that allows user to choose from any date in the past; other pickers allow the user to only choose from 'Now' and future dates. Others allow users to select a month but only choose 6 months in the future etc. I have about 4 more variant configurations.

My question is: Is there a way to have a basic configuration that sets all the common elements of the plugin i.e. prev, next buttons, which are always the same - then i would like to setup the specific 'different' features **inline** on that particular 'instance' of the datepicker in the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Found what i was looking for

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( options )
```